# Designing an invitation that will be emailed

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to know how big to build it so it's viewable on a variety of devices and I also need to know how I make it visible when someone opens the email WITHOUT having to open an attachment.

Comment: You are better off not using InDesign, which is a very good screwdriver, for your unrelated nail problems.

Comment: You tagged this with InDesign but say without having to open an attachment so I'm very confused. Are you sending an HTML Email or what?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to do a bit more research on how to design and create HTML emails, then come back to us with any issues you might still have.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be a spoilsport but I actually read my email with a text based system (because its fast, no blindingly fast, to read posts that way) So there is no way i can see your invitation without opening it up in a different program (in other words an attachment). But beside my rather weird corner case you would have to be able to cope with quite many devices.

With that covered we can now take a look at how you could do this. First InDewign is nonideal as the only way to send anything fancy it is either sendingn a HTML page or attaching a picture which most applications will show below the post in the editor. Both are non- ideal in many ways.

The picture is easy for you to make. But its going to waste space and potentially be problematic on a mobile device. It does not reflow and it does not nesseserily show up on all devices.

That leaves you the HTML option. Unfortunately the internal authoring tools of mail systems leave something to be desired, outlook made ones actually get penalty points on spam filters. Also many mail applications are quite quirky when it comes to html support to try keeping things as simple as possible.

Unfortunately print workflows dont work well in the digital delivery world. :(